# Microsoft Lync Group Chat Install error

Tags: lync

I'm trying to install Group Chat Server but I got this error:
**site:microsoft.com failed while applying server changes error creating a trusted application**
I installed and configured all the software requisites, created the users in the AD, created the DB and gave the proper permissions to the OCSChannel and OCSChat. But I am installing GC in the same server where Lync Server 2010 is. Is that a mistake? Do I have to install GC in other front end server?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself. I did not payed atention; when the wizard asked me for the hostname of my Lync Server, I filled it with the name of the machine, not the FQDN (I have the Lync Server 2010 Standard Edition).